# Apagar pantalla Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

como les va. Les comento estoy tratando de apagar la pantalla del ubuntu server y no hay caso.
Les comento.
Tengo un ubuntu server montado en una laptop. La funcion de este server es que este encendido y nada mas, no tiene sentido de que la pantalla permanezca encendida.

Estoy intentando con el siguiente comando desde una consola via ssh:

```
xset dpms force off
```

Al ejecutar ese comando me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

```
xset:  unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Siendo la ip del servidor 192.168.0.183, intente ejcutar los siguiente y de igual formas obtengo el mismo mensaje.

```
xset -display 192.268.0.183:0.0 dpms force off
```

xset:  unable to open display "192.268.0.183:0.0"

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3):

Creo que poner el brillo de la pantalla en **cero** cuenta como apagarla, con este metodo el brillo de tu pantalla vuelve a su **estado normal** cuando reinicies el sistema.
En el directorio */sys/class/backlight* encontramos los dispositivos disponibles correspondientes a nuestro hardware que a su vez se relacionan con la pantalla:

```sh
$ ls  /sys/class/backlight/
acpi_video0  intel_backlight  toshiba
```

Para mi caso concreto me funciona entrar en el directorio `intel_backlight` y alli existe un archivo llamado `brightness` que nos indica con un numero el brillo actual, este brillo actual puede estar comprendido entre 0 y el numero que tengas en el fichero `max_brightness` en el mismo directorio.
Lo que debes de hacer es editar el archivo `brightness` como root y dejarlo en **0** para "apagar tu pantalla", lo puedes hacer con nano:

```
nano /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con ésto

primero instalas el servicio vbetool:

```
sudo apt-get install vbetool
```

Para apagar el monitor una vez instalado el servicio:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

para recuperar el visionado de la consola:

```
sudo sh -c 'vbetool dpms off; read ans; vbetool dpms on'
```

Para no tener que teclear tanto texto, puedes hacer dos script, uno para apagar el monitor con la primera línea una vez instalado el servicio y otro para recuperar el control con la segunda línea

EDITADO:

Creo que tu error se solucionaría montando y desmontando antes de usar los comandos

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
vbetool dpms force off
sudo mount -o remount,noexec /dev
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, intente pero continuo con el mismo inconveniente.

`sudo apt-get install vbetool

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
vbetool ya está en su versión más reciente (1.1-4).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
maxedrom@maxedromsvr:~$ sudo vbetool dpms off
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface).`

Comment: Te respondo en mi respuesta

Comment: Me funcionó, gracias. Lo estaba buscando para un script.